# how to Multiple HttpHeader(with same name) in ExpressJS

Tags: php, node.js, http, express

My Php Code can be send two headers with same name, in php second parameter is for replace or override. but in ExpressJS  `res.header` is not like php code
PHP Code:

```
header("Link: <http://$prefetch_next_img>; rel=prefetch",false); 
header("Link: <http://$prefetch_next_img2>; rel=prefetch",false);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

ExpressJS(NodeJS) :

```
res.header('Link','Fake Value');
res.header('Link','Only Send it'); // previous header replaced
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to send more than one header with the same name?

Comment: Ya this isnt possible

Comment: You should take a look at this, it's for cookie, but the same process applies for headers I believe. Try it out and tell us please! :)
http://www.connecto.io/blog/nodejs-express-how-to-set-multiple-cookies-in-the-same-response-object/ - The solution is simply to send an array of values instead of just the values one by one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ultimately, you'll need to pass an array to set multiple values for the same header

```
res.header('Set-Cookie', ['foo', 'bar']);
```

Looking at [response library](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/aaa9690bcfca426efde7092ff72fa15cb9bf86a9/lib/response.js#L740-L756) for express we can see the following examples:

```
/**
 * Set header `field` to `val`, or pass
 * an object of header fields.
 *
 * Examples:
 *
 *    res.set('Foo', ['bar', 'baz']);
 *    res.set('Accept', 'application/json');
 *    res.set({ Accept: 'text/plain', 'X-API-Key': 'tobi' });
 *
 * Aliased as `res.header()`.
 *
 * @param {String|Object} field
 * @param {String|Array} val
 * @return {ServerResponse} for chaining
 * @public
 */
```

A deeper dive into the code shows us that this is really just a proxy for node's [response.setHeader()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value), which follows the same format

> Sets a single header value for implicit headers. If this header
> already exists in the to-be-sent headers, its value will be replaced.
> Use an array of strings here if you need to send multiple headers with
> the same name.

```
response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['type=ninja', 'language=javascript']);
```